# Save a version of .aux file

Tags: tcolorbox, auxiliary-files, xr

I want to use a specific version of the .aux file. So I want to save this version for an eventual use with the `xr` package. Is there a way to do this task ?

Note that the origin of this problem is from the `tcolorbox` package, what I use to produce exercises with upper part, and lower part of solutions containing labels from the upper part. This can be solved by an option for the upper part, which does not exist as aI know, similar to the option `tcblower=invisible`.

The origin of the problem is from the production of exercises and solutions by using the same following file:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=solutions/Solution-#1.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/Solution-#1.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\newtoggle{Exos}            %% Exercise or solution

\toggletrue{Exos}   
\togglefalse{Exos}


\newcommand\printExoSol[1]{\iftoggle{Exos}{\import{exercises/}{#1}}{\solution{#1}{solutions/Solution-#1.tex}}}
%% Produces upper part if true and lower part if false

\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
The page \thepage \ of the total number of \pageref{LastPage} pages

\printExoSol{Exo1}

\end{document}
```

The command `\printExoSol{Exo1}` compiles the file `Exo1` in integrality under the option `\toggletrue{Exos}` and only its lower part, which is the solution, under the option `\togglefalse{Exos}`. The file `Exo1`, what I put in the subfolder `exercises`, puts its lower part in the subfolder `solutions`.

I give the file `Exo1`, of the subfolder `exercises`:

```
\begin{exercise}{Exo1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Exercise with label
\begin{equation}
\label{Eqlabel}
\end{equation}
\tcblower
Solution with reference \eqref{Eqlabel}
\vspace*{2cm}

\lipsum[1]
\end{exercise}
```

With ths method, I can produce with this file, the exercises under the first option, and the solutions of the exercises under the second option.

But there is a problem of lose of the labels in the successive compilations: under the option `\toggletrue{Exos}` I obtain the following file:

[image]

under the option `\togglefalse{Exos}` I obtain the following file in the first compilation, where the labels are true but not the number of pages:

[image]

Then the second compilation, where the labels are lost and the number of pages is true:

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do you want to generate automatically two different aux files?

Comment: Yes. I want to generate an aux file a first time to use it several times... but the second use will erase the first aux file because it doesn't contain the label of the first... I compile first the hole document containing the upper and lower parts, which are exercises and solutions, respectively. Then generate in a second time, only the solution, so the information of the upper part will be lost...

Comment: It will be easier to understand if you can provide a complete example.

Comment: I'll give an example

Comment: Please see the edit of the file. All this can be simply solved by an option of `tcolorbox`, like the following, `tcbupper=invisible`, which does not exist, alas

Comment: I think that a solution can be found by a command, enabling the systematic copy of the labels of the upper part in the `aux` material of the lower bound...